# ПРАВИЛЬНОСТЬ НАПИСАНИЯ

Tags: склонение

как правильно пишется - в тетраде или в тетради ?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь всё решает грамматический род в сочетании с окончанием именительного падежа. Если имеется в виду тетрад**а** (группа из 4 клеток - биол. термин), то предложный падеж: в тетрад**е**;  если же тетрад**ь** (тоже ж. р., но нулевое окончание) -  то в тетрад**и**. Ср. дожд**ь** (**м. р.**) - при дожд**е** (предл. падеж).